# Setting the Maximum Timeout for an AWS Step Function Task in CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

I am working on an AWS Step Function workflow using the AWS CDK, and I have a task in my workflow that sends a message to an SQS queue. I want to set a maximum timeout for this task to ensure it keeps the task token alive when the AWS Lambda keeps trying.

```
this.intoFifoQueueTask = new SqsSendMessage(this, "Send to Queue", {
  queue: sqsStack.intoNS,
  timeout: Duration.minutes(15),
  // Other task configuration...
});
```

What is the max `timeout` I can put?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 year for standard state machines, 5 minutes for express, which is the maximum total execution time for the entire state machine: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/limits-overview.html

> Maximum execution time
>
> Standard: 1 year (constrained by the maximum execution time)
>
> Express: 5 minutes (constrained by the maximum execution time)